# Side effect of the Django form method `is_valid()`: intance updated?

Tags: django, django-forms

In `views.py`, I update an `article` instance as follows:

```
def articleUpdate(request, articleId):

    ...

    articleToUpdate = get_object_or_404(Article, id=articleId)

    ...

    # POST
    articleForm = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=articleToUpdate)

    print(articleToUpdate)

    if not articleForm.is_valid():
        return render(request, template, {...})

    print(articleToUpdate)

    articleForm.save()

    ...
```

The second printing of object `articleToUpdate` shows that it is changed. Is this a side effect of the method `is_valid()`? What's going on?

Comment: Could you add what the console is logging please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `form.is_valid()` for a model form, the instance is updated. This has been the behaviour [since Django 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.2/#modelform-is-valid-and-modelform-errors).

If you to access the original instances, then fetch the object from the database twice in your view.

```
# passed to form, will be updated in place
articleToUpdate = get_object_or_404(Article, id=articleId)
# not passed to form, will be unchanged
unchanged_article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=articleId)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am curious about why such behaviour is necessary?